# Linux mail command not working like it used to

Tags: mail, postfix, sendmail

I was using the following mail command in my crontab to which worked flawlessly until we re installed our mail server last Friday:

```
echo "Testing 123" | mail -s "ECS PostDate Processed" "layton.everson@gmail.com chrish@mycreditcompany.com" -- -r "noreply@mycreditcompany.com" -F "ServerCronJobs"
```

previously the "--" would rout the command line parameters to sendmail to send from a name and add a reply-to address.  Now it seems the -- is being ignored and all of the extra parameters are being treated as email addresses. so the email is going to:

```
from root <root@mycompany.com>
to me, chrish, -r, noreply, -F, ServerCronJobs
```

What is missing now?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what Ubuntu version you used in the past and which you are using right now? And do you have the old mail server still in reach? Or at least a package list backup? (e.g. something like `dpkg --get-selections > mypackages`)

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise

Comment: dpkg --get-selections > mypackages returns no results ...  I think it was postfix though.

Comment: It has saved the output to `mypackages`, it should return nothing, all should be in the file. Anyway, you need that from the *old* server. What version of Ubuntu was the *old* server running? Same perhaps, but you didn't answer that part. And please **edit** your question to provide all the new details you gave in these scattered comments. It's not a forum, but a Q&A site, you see? :)

Comment: Oh I understand, Its not an old server, I just messed with the mail programs... didn't change servers.

Comment: Oh, I see now. This "I reinstalled our mail server" is a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mail` points to one of the alternatives.

```
ls -l /usr/bin/mail
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Jan  5  2011 /usr/bin/mail -> /etc/alternatives/mail

ls -l /etc/alternatives/mail
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Jan  5  2011 /etc/alternatives/mail -> /usr/bin/bsd-mailx
```

You were probably using another mail program in the past. Try to figure out which it was.

After you have installed the right package, then change the alternative like this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config mail
```

Comment: # ls -l /usr/bin/mail 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 May 13 17:43 /usr/bin/mail -> /etc/alternatives/mail
# ls -l /etc/alternatives/mail
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 May 13 17:43 /etc/alternatives/mail -> /usr/bin/mail.mailutils

Comment: root@mycreditcompany:/srv/www/homedev.mycreditcompany.com# sudo update-alternatives --config mail
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for mail.

Comment: Please point me to a resource about 'adding' mail alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, it is a link to `/etc/alternatives/mail`.
you can see that (if you have any package which provides it already installed) by `readlink /usr/bin/mail` and locate the existing package by `readlink -f /usr/bin/mail`

It is provided by any package which provides the `mail-reader` you can search for one with `apt-cache search mail-reader` personally I use `bsd-mailx`.