# Bash Script for custom message

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, email

I'm trying to send an email using bash script.

I tried using the following in the bash script with no success as I execute the script it asks for CC:

```
#!/bin/bash
recipient="tarun@gmail.com"
mail -s "This is a test mail" "$recipient"
```

but nothing seems to work as I want it to be automated.

Also I want to send a message with the mail I went through different tutorials but in every tutorial a message is written in a text file then the file is sent but can't I write a message with the mail command itself and not save it to any file and send it. Please Help.

P.S.

I just want the script to do the following

If a particular operation is complete then it sends an email to the recipient with a subject and a message saying operation is completed successfully.

Comment: Could you include the output of `ls -l /etc/alternatives/mail` in your question? It's possible you have installed a different `mail` client than I have, so this makes it hard to verify answers. (I can provide an answer how to send a message with it from within the script, btw.)

Comment: It is like this                                                             ls -l /etc/alternatives/mailx
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jun 20 13:15 /etc/alternatives/mailx -> /usr/bin/mail

Comment: I didn't ask for `mailx`, but for `mail`, the command you're running. See also this answer: [mail alternatives](http://askubuntu.com/a/295479/88802) and the comments on it. Please **edit** your question for providing more information - this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site, you see.

Comment: There's nothing like /etc/alternatives/mail its /etc/alternatives/mailx

Comment: Are you sure you've installed it using Ubuntu packages? Please provide the output of `which mail | xargs dpkg -S`.

Comment: I had installed mailutils using apt-get install mailutils.              which mail | xargs dpkg -S                                               shows                                                                      mailutils: /usr/bin/mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending a body with GNU mailutils in a script should work like this:

```
echo -e "body of message \nAnd use newlines for new lines." | mail -s "the subject" recipient@domain.tld
```

It should not ask for a CC address interactively in this mode (reading from `stdin` using the pipe `|`).

Comment: Thanks I just needed the heirloom-mailx package as well. @ Oli: Thanks alot :)

Comment: `bsd-mailx` or the regular GNU `mailutils` will also work, as far as I know.

Comment: For new lines to work, add `-e` to the echo command: `echo -e "This will\nsuccessfully break\nlines`

Comment: @Nicolas true, thanks. :) Next time, feel free to edit a post.

Answer (score 3):

`mail` expects a body either from `stdin` or after the command runs (in interactive mode). The simple way around this problem is to just echo into the command like so:

```
echo | mail -s "Test subject" "oli@example.com"
```

Note that's using `mail` from the `heirloom-mailx` package.

Answer (score 0):

```
(
    echo "To: 
    example@gmail.com"
    echo "From: system <root>"
    echo "Subject: Rails Energy Valut Failure on `hostname` (`hostname --ip-address`) - `date` server restart"
 ) 2>&1 | /usr/lib/sendmail -t
```